# HTML scrollbar half working half not working

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/rLP2e/)

```
table#projectTable > tbody ,  table#productTable > tbody{
            height: 300px;
            overflow: auto;
}
```

The scroll bar is working if you click the upper part but not the lower part.
Very strange.

I used firefox inspect element and I think its something to do with the TR element overlapping because the scrollbar is working fine just above the (imaginary extended line from ) second row (Edit product info)

[image]

Comment: Is it possible for you to publish your full code (or a reduced example)?

Comment: I uploaded in on jsfiddle, link is there in the question

Comment: Oops, didn't see that was a link. I can't replicate the bug on my end.

Comment: What browser are you using, IE? It works for me in Chrome.

Comment: Can someone tell me  that if you can see the image in the question, i cant, company policy, uploaded sites are blocked.

Comment: @JonathanWilson firefox 30.0

Comment: I can see it just fine

Comment: The scrollbar is fully functional in the jsFiddle using Chrome 35.0.1916.153.

Comment: Not an issue in Chrome or IE 10. Firefox Windows only?

Comment: @Jonathan try scrolling by using the lower arrow, it won't work. While it work properly on the top arrow

Comment: You are right, doesn't work in FireFox 30

Comment: @HarendraSingh, Yep I can see the image.

Comment: for people saying that it work, please see the image, i said it wont work from below, try pressing the down arrow

Comment: @Harenda it didn't work in any of firefox, IE, safari, opera, or chrome

Comment: @HarendraSingh, Interestingly enough, the line you drew corresponds to the second `<tr>` element in your table.  Maybe try a different layout and see what happens?

Comment: for temp solution `.innerDiv{position:absolute;top:80px;left:185px;z-index:10;}`

Comment: @marathonman just added position : absolute, and it worked !!!, dont know whats the problem is

Comment: @marathonman can you write this as answer so that I can accept it ?

Comment: @HarendraSingh after your message i've checked your html, your problem with rows, i'll enter an answer with your table design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i say at comments

```
.innerDiv{position:absolute;top:80px;left:185px;z-index:10;}
```

will solve your problem.

maby you already know but if you dont may i kindly suggest you that give a chance to tableless design when you design a layout.

for example - also this sample could be better -

[preview](http://jsfiddle.net/rLP2e/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="left">

        <a href="#" onclick="hide('table1')">Edit branchInfo</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="hide('table2')">Edit branchInfo</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="hide('table3')">Edit projectList</a>

    </div>

    <div id="right">
        <div id="table1"> ...1... </div>
        <!--#table1-->
        <div id="table2"> ...2... </div>
        <!--#table2-->
        <div id="table3"> ...3... </div>
        <!--#table3-->
    </div>
    <!--#right-->

    <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
<!--#container-->
```

**CSS**

```
  .clear {
      clear: left;
  }

  #container {
      border: 1px solid #666;
      padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  }

  #left, #right {
      float: left;
  }

      #left a {
          display: block;
          width: 100px;
          height: 200px;
          font: 12px/200px arial;
          border: 1px solid #999;
          margin-bottom: 5px;
          padding: 10px;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-weight: bold;
          color: #666;
      }

          #left a:hover {
              background: #efefef;
          }

          #left a:active {
              background: #c0c0c0;
          }

  #right {
      border: 1px solid #999;
      margin-left: 5px;
      padding: 10px;
      height: 654px;
      width: 900px;
  }
```